# Java (NetBeans) Save Image from URL to Local

Tags: java, netbeans

I'm trying to import a CSV file into a MySQL database. That works perfectly. The problem arises when I try to download an image file from a URL to the server where the servlet is running and save it there.

It works perfectly when I run the servlet on my local machine in NetBeans IDE. It downloads the file, changes it's size finishes. When I try it on the server running in a browser it throws an exception and says it can't find the directory/file.

This is my current code:

```
try {
    saveImage(item[3], idir + prod + ".jpg");
} catch (IOException ioe) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ioe.getMessage());
}

public static void saveImage ( String imageUrl, String destinationFile ) throws IOException {
    URL url = new URL(imageUrl);
    InputStream is = url.openStream();
    OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(destinationFile);

        byte[] b = new byte[2048];
    int length;

    while ((length = is.read(b)) != -1) {
        os.write(b, 0, length);
    }

    is.close();
        os.close();
    }
```

Like I said, this works perfectly from my local system, only when it's running as a servlet on the server does it not work anymore.

The only other option I am thinking is to run a CLI command from Java and just use WGET to download the file in question. But I would like to steer clear of that if possible.

Comment: A server file system is different from the local file system. For security reasons, you can not call a url in the browser and save a file on the local computer. On the server, for example in `var/www/htdocs` it is possible but only if the directory `xyz` already exists.

Comment: It gets the file, that's not the problem. I want to save it TO the server. Getting the file from the URL is never the problem. Pleas read it fully before posting. Thanks.

Comment: `It works perfectly when I run the servlet on my local machine` . If server and client are on the same machine you can save the file wherever you want.

Comment: I wish you would read the post before answering comments. THEY ARE NOT on the same machine. NetBeans is my local dev environment and the server is remote where it's finally uploaded as a Servlet served by HTML and apache. Please read before posting.